# Joining two tables and adding another column SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two tables and calculating another column.

These are the [two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd4Em.png). I am trying to create a new column

```
BVC = ScaleFactor * BookingValue / Clicks
```

I tried using:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (s.scaling factor * m.BookingValue) / clicks AS BVC label = ’BVC’
FROM 
    maintable m, Scale s
WHERE
    maintable.keyword = s.keyword
```

I know it's definitely wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s And even [Modern SQL](https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/modern-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
SELECT m.*, s.*,
       (s.scaleFactor * m.BookingValue)/clicks as BVC
FROM maintable m JOIN
     Scale s
     ON m.keyword = s.keyword;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- You have defined a table alias for `maintable`.  You then need to use it.
- The column name in your description is `scaleFactor` rather than `scale factor`..
- Use simple column names and `as` to assign column aliases.

The above is standard SQL and should work in any database.